# put UIScrollView on a CollectionViewCell but the scrollview can not scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I put an `UIScrollView` on a `CollectionViewCell` but the `scrollview` can not scroll

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell<UIScrollViewDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *toolsScrollView;


}


@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        //wangzheng
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            NSArray *nibView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCollectionViewCell"owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *bw = [nibView objectAtIndex:0] ;
            [self.contentView addSubview:bw];
            toolsScrollView.delegate=self;


            UIView *toolView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
            toolView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            toolView1.frame = CGRectMake(300, 0, 80, 150);
            [toolsScrollView addSubview:toolView1];


            toolsScrollView.delegate=self;
            [toolsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400 * 2, toolsScrollView.frame.size.height)];
            toolsScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
            toolsScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
            toolsScrollView.delegate = self;
            toolsScrollView.userInteractionEnabled=true;
            toolsScrollView.scrollEnabled=true;
        }
        return self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

`IBOutlet UIScrollView *toolsScrollView` links to the `UIScrollView` in XIB

[image]

the scrollview can not scroll and the function `scrollViewDidScroll` never be triggered

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the collectionView steal the touch events from the scrollView ?

Comment: UICollectionViewCell is subclass of UIView

Comment: Has related code in your collectionView?

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues :

1. toolsScrollView variable is not connected and not pointing to a valid scrollview or,
2. The frame of the toolsScrollView is not correct after loading from the nib. or,

3.It's actually scrolling but not visible, so for testing purpose enabled the following -

```
toolsScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
toolsScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
```